# Order Error Creating Duplicate Entry

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

A customer has paid yet his order is stuck in his shopping cart. I confirmed this with looking in my paypal his payment has definitely gone through.

So I tried to Create an order for him so I could give him invoice...etc. Upon trying to create an invoice it gives me error;

> Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   1062 Duplicate entry '100000103' for key
>   'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `sales_flat_order` (`coupon_code`, `protect_code`,
>   `shipping_description`, `is_virtual`, `store_id`, `customer_id`,
>   `base_discount_amount`, `base_grand_total`, `base_shipping_amount`,
>   `base_shipping_tax_amount`, `base_subtotal`, `base_tax_amount`,
>   `base_to_global_rate`, `base_to_order_rate`, `discount_amount`,
>   `grand_total`, `shipping_amount`, `shipping_tax_amount`,
>   `store_to_base_rate`, `store_to_order_rate`, `subtotal`, `tax_amount`,
>   `total_qty_ordered`, `customer_is_guest`, `customer_note_notify`,
>   `customer_group_id`, `quote_id`, `base_shipping_discount_amount`,
>   `base_subtotal_incl_tax`, `shipping_discount_amount`,
>   `subtotal_incl_tax`, `weight`, `customer_dob`, `increment_id`,
>   `applied_rule_ids`, `base_currency_code`, `customer_email`,
>   `customer_firstname`, `customer_lastname`, `customer_middlename`,
>   `customer_prefix`, `customer_suffix`, `customer_taxvat`,
>   `discount_description`, `global_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`,
>   `remote_ip`, `shipping_method`, `store_currency_code`, `store_name`,
>   `x_forwarded_for`, `customer_note`, `created_at`, `updated_at`,
>   `total_item_count`, `customer_gender`, `hidden_tax_amount`,
>   `base_hidden_tax_amount`, `shipping_hidden_tax_amount`,
>   `base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt`, `shipping_incl_tax`,
>   `base_shipping_incl_tax`, `coupon_rule_name`, `gift_message_id`)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2016-03-10 03:27:10', '2016-03-10 03:27:10',
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

It says the Duplicate Entry "100000103" already exists which it does when I look in my invoices. I've taken my website offline for now until I get this sorted as I don't want to tarnish my brand.

Anyone had this error before?

EDIT1: I tried to create again and it went to "100000104" then "100000105", upon the fourth try it worked as it defaulted to "100000106" which does not have a sale number.

Thanks, Steve

Comment: Please be more clear as to how you fixed this

Comment: Which version of magento are you using? I have a fix for this on my magento 1.9.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue. You need to change your `increment_last_id` of your `invoice` entity type.

By default in magento invoice entity type is **6**. Which you can find in `eav_entity_type` table.

You need to change `increment_last_id` value for your store. The `increment_last_id` is in `eav_entity_store` table. You can run following query to update your invoice `increment_last_id`. Where **X** is your new `increment_last_id` and **STORE_ID_HERE** is your store id to whom you changing shipment `increment_last_id`.

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
       INNER JOIN eav_entity_type
         ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET    eav_entity_store.increment_last_id = 'X'
WHERE  eav_entity_type.entity_type_code = 'invoice'
       AND eav_entity_store.store_id = {STORE_ID_HERE};
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE `eav_entity_store` SET `increment_last_id` = 'X' WHERE `entity_type_id` = '6';
```

**Notice that the value for increment_last_id already contains the increment_prefix. Use your entity_type increment_prefix**

For more details check here : https://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I actually worked this out just before you replied! Thankyou anyway for the reassurance I did the right thing.
I added 10 increments on each entity.